# Use extern in three src file

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have three files:
header.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER_
#define _HEADER_

int var = 0;

#endif
```

src1.cpp

```
#include "somefile.h" 
extern int var;
int main(void) { // error: first defined here
    var = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

src2.cpp

```
#include "somefile.h"
extern int var;

int foo () { // error : multiple definition of 'var'
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why 'extern' keyword can't use in this situation. How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way around. Put the `extern` declaration in the header file, include it whenever the variable is needed, and in one source file define it.

Is it is now, every source file that includes your header will have their own definition, and those will clash with each other when you link your program.

Answer (score 4):

put the declaration of

```
int var = 0;
```

in one of the cpp file and not in the header file

and put the

```
extern int var;
```

in the header file only

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, somefile.h includes header.h.

When you extern a variable you want to, as you've done, have that variable be non-extern in exactly one place. Make that place a .c file.  If it's a header file every place it's included will get its own copy, leading to "multiple definitions of 'var'"

Move

```
int var = 0;
```

into one of the src files.